# Run logit function on a large dataset in R using glm

Tags: r, glm

I try to construct a simple Logit function using glm but I can't find a way to make it work. The main reason is that I am totally new to R, hence please forgive my naive question if that's too simple.

The issue I face is that I can't find a way to run the simple Logit function command for my data. I do the following.

`mydata<- read.csv("C:/Users/gp/TabTransformerNets/Pneu_features_pivoted.csv")`

`mylogit <- glm(target ~ mydata[,1:2169], data = mydata, family = "binomial")`

The target column in mydata is the dependent variable on which I want to run the Logit for calculating odds ratios. However, I get the following error:

Error in model.frame.default(formula = target ~ mydata[, 1:2169],  :
invalid type (list) for variable 'mydata[, 1:2169]'

I can't find a way to solve this, could you please help?

[part of the dataset snap shot, here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXMAi.png)

Comment: `glm(target ~ ., data = mydata, family = "binomial")` might be what you're looking for? `glm` is looking for a formula composed of variable names. The `.` means "all other variables".

Comment: Thank you very much @AndyBaxter. My data seem to be quite large and I got a warning that the glm.fit function did not converge. But, your suggestion helped a lot. I may get the 150-200 most important features from logistic regression, and then run only these for glm.fit to derive their odds ratios.

Comment: @MichaelSmith You have 2170 regressors but 1594 < 2170 observations, you probably need a different method such as PCA. I recommend to consult your local statistician.

Comment: Thanks for your note @michaelsmith. PCA can certainly be used for ML analysis (such as to reduce multi-colinearities in logistic regression or more complex models), but I think it overcomplicates things when it comes to estimating feature importance (OR, which I aim to do here) on PCA-ed features. There is a way to perform something like Logistic Regression (which undergoes regularization), get the top most important features and then run the logit (does non-regularized calculations) to estimate OR values. I will have a look and see.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Andy Baxter above, the quick solution for this is:

`glm(target ~ ., data = mydata, family = "binomial")`